# Which one is correct? "Voller" or "voll von"?

Tags: difference

Which is correct? *Voller* or *voll von*?

1. Ich habe ein Haus ***voller*** Blumen gesehen.
2. Ich habe ein Haus ***voll von*** Blumen gesehen.

Comment: another option I've seen recently on zeit.de: „Haus voll Blumen“ ;-)http://blog.zeit.de/ladurnerulrich/2015/07/06/ein-land-voll-nackter-ziegel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct. There is a [perposition](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/voller), actually derived from the adjective *voll*, to denote that something is full: *voller*, in the meaning *angefüllt mit*.
The choice you do, it's a matter of style.

An example (due to Emmanuel) is

> Vieler Hände Arbeit ~ Arbeit vieler Hände ~ Arbeit von vielen Händen

Comment: Wouldn't "voller Blumen" be rather equivalent to "von vollen Blumen?" (though I agree it doesn't make sense)?

Comment: @karoshi I don't think so. Try adding an adjective: *voll mit schönen Blumen* vs. *voll schöner Blumen*.

Comment: Since "das Buch meiner Mutter" -> "das Buch von meiner Mutter", "ein Haus voller Blumen" should also be equivalent to "ein Haus von vollen Blumen".

Comment: @karoshi grammatically correct, but thanks to the ambivalence of *"voller"* ("voll von" vs. fem. pl. "voll"), it makes more sense to interpret this as "voll von".

Comment: I wasn't aware of this ambivalence. Thanks!

Comment: I think @karoshi has got a point here. The logic is flawed. I'll demonstrate it using another adjective "Vieler Hände Arbeit" = "die Arbeit vieler Hände" = "die Arbeit von vielen Händen". The comments do some explanation but the answer as it is is misleading IMO

Comment: @Emanuel ich wüsste nicht, wie ich das erklären soll. Ich schreibe vorübergehend dein Beispiel in meiner Antwort.

Answer (score 2):

As said already, both are correct.
To add another option, it is also possible to say:

> Ich habe ein Haus ***voll mit*** Blumen.

Especially used in the following case:

> Ich habe einen Kühlschrank ***voll mit*** Getränken.

which translates to

> I have a fridge full of beverages.

I don't know anybody who would say

> Ich habe einen Kühlschrank ***voll von*** Getränken.

**Edit**
For clearification: I don't want to say it would be wrong to say `voll von Getränken`. It may just sound strange and/or uncommon to some people. I have never heard it being used.

Comment: "Nobody would say" sounds like an awful generalization. While it might be rare in spoken usage, it is a perfectly fine and common phrase in written, especially formal language.

Comment: Mh you may be right, I'll rephrase it.

Comment: Although I for one would not hesitate to say: "Ich habe einen Kühlschrank voller Getränke."

Comment: Yeah ofc `voller Getränke` would be fine for me as well. But I have never heard someone say `voll von Getränken` or `voll von Essen`.

Comment: "voll von Getränken" klingt falsch für mich. Das würde ich noch nicht mal über Personen sagen, die zu viel getrunken haben.